# How to split a byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, split, byte, delimiter

Let's take this byte array:

`[FF 11 11 FF FF 22 22 22 FF FF 33 33 33 33 FF]`

and let's choose the delimiter to be

`[FF]`

Then the split will result in these three parts:

`[11 11]
[22 22 22]
[33 33 33 33]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write (a couple of) methods to achieve this, e.g.:

```
private List<byte[]> split(byte[] array, byte value){
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Byte> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(byte element : array){
        if(element == value && !subList.isEmpty()){
            list.add(convertToPrimitiveArray(subList));
            subList = new ArrayList<>();
        }else if(element != value){
            subList.add(element);
        }
    }
    if(!subList.isEmpty()){
        list.add(convertToPrimitiveArray(subList));
    }
    return list;
}

private byte[] convertToPrimitiveArray(List<Byte> list){
    byte[] array = new byte[list.size()];
    for(int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

It returns the list of `byte` arrays by splitting the main array with provided value.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! that s a solution! and i have last question: sometimes i get byte FF as data between delimiters and to prevent delimiting at wrong position i use an escape symbol (flag that means next value is not delimiter) before it (lets suppose BB) then i have FF 11 11 FF FF 22  22 22 BB FF 22 FF FF 33 33 FF how to to solve that?

Comment: In that case, we need to change the first for loop (that iterates over byte array) and put a couple of conditions to check next and/or previously scanned elements, it shouldn't be difficult.